# Connecting cassandra to Tableau Software

Tags: odbc, cassandra-2.0, tableau-api

I want to connect Tableau software to my cassandra database. Note that i'm using tableau in windows7 and cassandra in ubuntu (Virtual machine).
For this i've installed the Cassandra ODBC (and Simba cassandra ODBC but i got the same problem). I got a connexion succes and i found my keyspace but not my tables !!!!!!

[image: Connexion success]

[image: No table]

But no table in "cim" keyspace  !!

Note that in my keyspace "cim" i have 3 tables that i can request with any problem in cassandra. Is there something i should do before creating the ODBC driver ???

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODBC driver as it stands currently uses thrift so won't be able to communicate directly with cql3 to display the table names. Describe commands also won't work. However, you should still be able to select data from your tables. Updates to the ODBC driver should provide cql3 support at some point in the new year.

Comment: It's not clear whether you mean the Simba ODBC driver or the Cassandra ODBC driver.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I was referring to the Cassandra ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Update Simba ODBC driver for Cassandra supports CQL3 and solves your problem.

http://www.simba.com/connectors/apache-cassandra-odbc